# JQuery ui tabs remove/hide <li> in <ul> if div doesn't exist on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Code:

```
<div id="alert-view-tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#general-tab-alert-view">General information</a></li>
                <li><a href="#alert-sections-view">Alert Items</a></li>
                <li><a href="#alert-operators-view">Operators</a></li>
                <li><a href="#AlertPlanTypeAudienceView">Plan Type & Audience</a></li>
                <li><a href="#AlertDiscountOffersView">Discount Offers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#AlertStandartPlanView">Standard Plans</a></li>
                <li><a href="#AlertDataOnlyPlanView">Data Only Plans</a></li>
                <li><a href="#InternationalRatesAlertView">International Rates</a></li>
                <li><a href="#RoamingRatesAlertView">Roaming Rates</a></li>
            </ul>
```

In some situations, I have not `divs` in my page, which can you see above. So selector is empty, but I need to remove or hide tabs if div doesn't exist in the page. I'm new in JS and will be glad to get any help.

Comment: What are you asking is not clear.

Comment: It is clear to me. If the element that the anchor is referencing does not exist, remove it.

Comment: I need to remove it, after a page is loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the basic idea with the explanation.

```js
//So select all of the anchors
var anchors = $("#alert-view-tabs a");
//loop them
anchors.each(function() {
  //get the hash
  var id = this.hash
  //see if it exists
  var isThere = $(id).length === 1;
  //if not, remove the parent
  if (!isThere) {
      $(this).closest("li").remove();  
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="alert-view-tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#general-tab-alert-view">General information</a></li>
    <li><a href="#alert-sections-view">Alert Items</a></li>
    <li><a href="#alert-operators-view">Operators</a></li>
    <li><a href="#AlertPlanTypeAudienceView">Plan Type &amp; Audience</a></li>
    <li><a href="#AlertDiscountOffersView">Discount Offers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#AlertStandartPlanView">Standard Plans</a></li>
    <li><a href="#AlertDataOnlyPlanView">Data Only Plans</a></li>
    <li><a href="#InternationalRatesAlertView">International Rates</a></li>
    <li><a href="#RoamingRatesAlertView">Roaming Rates</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="general-tab-alert-view">general-tab-alert-view</div>
<div id="alert-operators-view">alert-operators-view</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over each `a` and remove it's parent `li` if the div doesn't exist.

```
$('#alert-view-tabs ul li a').each(function() {
    if (!($(this.href).length)) {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    }
});
```